# hlssink2 get-fragment-stream signal not triggered if requested after default

Tags: rust, gstreamer

have a rust pipeline that needs to know when a ts segment is written so that we can do some additional processing. I setup a signal callback for the "get-fragment-stream" and set the after value boolean to true so that I get notified after the default callback is called.

But if I set the after to true, I dont get notified at all after the file segments are written. It works if I set the flag to `false` that is before calling the default implementation.

The following is a code snippet of how it is implemented. I tried both the "connect" and "connect_closure" and it is the same result.

```
vod_sink.connect_closure(
                        "get-fragment-stream",
                        true, // after
                        glib::closure!(
                        move |_elem: &Element, filename: &str| -> FileOutputStream {
                                //TODO: use the file name to probe the file
                                let file = File::for_path(filename);
                                log::info!("vod-sink connect_closure callback filename={}", filename);
                                  match fs::metadata(&filename) {
                                    Ok(info) => log::info!("found the file in the path created={:?}", info.created()),
                                    Err(e) => log::error!("The file is not yet created={}", filename),
                                }
                                file.replace(None, false, FileCreateFlags::NONE, Cancellable::NONE).unwrap()
                            }),
                    );
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

I appreciate any help with this.

Comment: `get-fragment-stream` is always called _before_ the data is written, and it is supposed to open the file in which the data will be written. If you want some code to run after the data has been written and return it, you can wrap the `FileOutputStream` in a custom type, implement `Drop` on your wrapper, and put your post-processing in the `drop` implementation.